# How much of a football game can be played to determine an official result?

Tags: american-football, nfl

[What happens to an NFL game that is started and suspended?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28628/what-happens-to-an-nfl-game-that-is-started-and-suspended) talks about handling suspended games.

Is there a period of time that needs to be played to bring upon an official result? 9:02 of 60:00 of in-game clock may not be enough to determine a winner/loser/tie/no contest upon suspension but suppose a half is played - can a official result be determined by that?

I recall a game in the early 2000s that needed to be finished despite suspension and unruly crowd conditions so I'm inclined to believe that anything less than 60 minutes of in-game clock wouldn't determine an official result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading exactly the same [Rule 17](https://operations.nfl.com/media/5kvgzyss/2022-nfl-rulebook-final.pdf) as from the linked question: ARTICLE 4. EMERGENCY SITUATIONS.

**The NFL affirms the position that in most circumstances all regular-season and postseason games should be played to their conclusion.** If, in the opinion of appropriate League authorities, it is impossible to begin or continue a game due to an emergency ... the following procedures (Articles 5 through 11) will serve as guidelines for the Commissioner and/or the duly appointed representatives.

Ergo, if a NFL game cannot be played to its conclusion, the Commissioner has discretion to determine an official result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read exactly the same [Rule 17](https://operations.nfl.com/media/5kvgzyss/2022-nfl-rulebook-final.pdf) as from the linked question:

> ARTICLE 4. EMERGENCY SITUATIONS. [...] If, in the Commissioner’s opinion, it is reasonable to project that the resumption of an interrupted game would not change its ultimate result or adversely affect any other inter-team competitive issue, the Commissioner is empowered to terminate the game.

or once again, the Commissioner gets to decide.

Comment: Except that's not what I'm asking. In baseball, a winner/loser can be determined after playing 5 innings; I'm looking for an NFL equivalent if it exists.

Comment: It doesn't. NFL games are played to completion on the day except in emergency cases.